# Does Plato ever call God "Father"?

Tags: reference-request, theology, plato

[This article](https://journals.openedition.org/etudesplatoniciennes/448#ftn26) suggests in several places that Plato at times called God (or, perhaps the Demiurge) by the name of "Father". However, I cannot find any such primary sources to validate the claim. Is "Father" simply a translation of *demiourgos*, or did Plato really call God "Father"?

Comment: You might like "Drudgery Divine: On the Comparison of Early Christianities and the Religions of Late Antiquity" by Jonathan Z. Smith. He details the attempts to try and assign a 'Primitive Christianity' to the philosophies and religions of antiquity. It is an attempt to try to show that Christians and Chrsitianity pre-existed and is not a new or novel religion. The attempts have their primary roots from the late 16th century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory [search](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=en&inContent=true&q=father&doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0180%3Atext%3DTim.) finds six occurrences of "father" in the text of the *Timaeus*, in all cases the original word being πατήρ .

> 28c: Now to discover the Maker and Father of this Universe were a task indeed; 
> 37 c: And when the Father that engendered it perceived it in
> motion and alive,
> 41a: Those works whereof I am framer and father >are indissoluble save by my will. 
> 42e: His children gave heed to their
> Father's command and obeyed it. 
>  50d:  ... liken the Recipient to the
> Mother, the Source to the Father, and what is engendered between these
> two ...
>  71d: ... For they who constructed us, remembering the
> injunction of their Father, when He enjoined upon them to make the
> mortal

Plato is not writing of any "god" (with a capital g). According to dictionaries  δημιουργός (dēmiourgós), “one who works for the people; a skilled workman, a handicraftsman”, a compound work from demos and ergon, that is, a person working for the public/people.